# Matlab not displaying plot

Tags: matlab, plot, format, axis

I am trying to plot in Matlab. When I format the axis the plot does not show, but when I turn the formatting off it works. Not sure what I is wrong.

Format on vs format off

[image]

```
x=clim(:,2);
time=taxgen(199801,201012);
Year=find(time >= 1998 & time <= 2010);
plot(Year, x, 'r');
ax=gca;
ax.XLim = [1998 2010];
ax.XTick = [1998:2010];
ax.XTickLabelRotation = 45;
ax.YLim=[-10 10];
ax.YTick=[-10 -5 0 5 10]
grid on
```

Comment: What do you mean by turning the formatting on and off?

Comment: When I comment out the axis formatting, it shows the graph. https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HkWL.jpg

Comment: Your year likely doesn't have the values you think it does. It currently has the indices of the years in that range. I'm not sure it is what you really want to do, but to get the results you're looking for, you should use: `Year=time(time >= 1998 & time <= 2010);`

Comment: You were right, @Hector! Changing the find to time worked! Thank you!